# Tallying stringed labels

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have data set DF with stringed Labels for which I want to understand how often each label appears. My actual data is large and I need a way to generalize the code from what I've come up with below. Is there a better way to tally individual labels after I've split them (Step 2) into columns and to join them for a sum (Step 4)?
Any hints/help would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(splitstackshape)

DF <- data.frame(V=c("a","a","b","b","b"),V1=c("Place1-Place2-Place3-Place4-Place5-Place6-Place7",
                            "Place2-Place4-Place5-Place7-Place8",
                            "Place1-Place2-Place4-Place7-Place8-Place9",
                            "Place3-Place4-Place2-Place1",
                            "Place5-Place6"))
> DF
  V                                               V1
1 a Place1-Place2-Place3-Place4-Place5-Place6-Place7
2 a               Place2-Place4-Place5-Place7-Place8
3 b        Place1-Place2-Place4-Place7-Place8-Place9
4 b                      Place3-Place4-Place2-Place1
5 b                                    Place5-Place6

# 1 - split stringed Labels in V1 into new columns
DF2<-cSplit(DF, "V1", sep="-", direction = "wide")

# 2 - tally Labels per new column
C1_f <- DF2 %>%
  group_by(V1_1) %>% rename(Label = V1_1) %>% 
  tally()

C2_f <- DF2 %>%
  group_by(V1_2) %>% rename(Label = V1_2) %>% 
  tally() %>% filter(Label!="")

C3_f <- DF2 %>%
  group_by(V1_3) %>% rename(Label = V1_3) %>% 
  tally() %>% filter(Label!="")

C4_f <- DF2 %>%
  group_by(V1_4) %>% rename(Label = V1_4) %>% 
  tally() %>% filter(Label!="")

C5_f <- DF2 %>%
  group_by(V1_5) %>% rename(Label = V1_5) %>% 
  tally() %>% filter(Label!="")

# 3 - Count total number of rows
Ctally <- DF2 %>% summarise(count=n())

# 4 - join all tallies by Label and plot in decreasing order
C1_f %>% 
  full_join(C2_f, by = "Label") %>%
  full_join(C3_f, by = "Label") %>%
  full_join(C4_f, by = "Label") %>%
  full_join(C5_f, by = "Label") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(n, n.x, n.y,n.x.x, n.y.y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(Label, sum) %>% mutate(pct = 100*sum/Ctally$count) %>%
  # arrange(desc(sum)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Label,(sum)), y=pct)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Label", y="% of the time Label appears in Row", fill="") +
  ggtitle("Labels Associated with Rows") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general `tidyverse` way,

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>% 
 mutate(cnt = n(), V1 = strsplit(as.character(V1), '-')) %>% 
 unnest() %>% 
 count(V1, cnt) %>% 
 mutate(percentage = 100*n/cnt) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = reorder(V1, percentage), y = percentage))+ 
 geom_col()+
 coord_flip()
```

Comment: so much to learn! thx. I've added a twist in that I want to facet by V in the end and my counts have to be per V level. I left this bit out originally because I thought i'd be able to manage but your code is so compact that I'm not sure where to start...other than group_by(V)?

Comment: You mean something like `DF %>% 
  mutate(cnt = n(), V1 = strsplit(as.character(V1), '-')) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(V) %>%
  count(V1, cnt) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = 100*n/cnt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(V1, percentage), y = percentage))+ 
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap( ~ V)`?

Comment: @val `count(V1, cnt)` acting similar to `group_by(V1, cnt) %>% tally() %>% ungroup()`. So just add V into a `count(V, V1, cnt)`

Comment: @Soto: Yes, except that I placed group_by() at the start and the percentages make more sense: DF %>% group_by(V) %>% mutate(cnt = n(), V1 = strsplit(as.character(V1), '-')) %>% unnest()  %>% count(V1, cnt) %>% mutate(percentage = 100*n/cnt) %>% ggplot(aes(x = reorder(V1, percentage), y = percentage))+ geom_col()+ coord_flip()+ facet_wrap( ~ V)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got a bit obsessed with `map()` lately, @Sotos aswer is cleaner and faster version of what I did.

---

'tidyverse' approach.

```
library('purrr')
library('stringr')
library('tidyr')
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')

DF <- data.frame(V=1:5,V1=c("Place1-Place2-Place3-Place4-Place5-Place6-Place7",
                            "Place2-Place4-Place5-Place7-Place8",
                            "Place1-Place2-Place4-Place7-Place8-Place9",
                            "Place3-Place4-Place2-Place1",
                            "Place5-Place6"))
DF2 <- DF %>% 
  mutate(V1 = map(V1,
                  ~ str_split(.x, pattern = '-', simplify = T) %>% 
                     t()
                  )
         ) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  tally()
```

The trick is that we transform a character column into column of nested `matrix` each consisting of one column with "Places". Then we just need to unnest it and count (`tally()`) the number of each "Place".

Here is the resulting plot:

```
DF2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = n, x = V1))+
  geom_col()+
  labs(y = 'Place Count',
       x = 'Places')+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the `map*` functions of `purrr` are quite useful. I need to dive in  there myself

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin: thx. when i run your code as is I get: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin: and if I add as.character(V1) I get: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'Place1-Place2-Place3-Place4-Place5-Place6-Place7MapEnv' not found

Comment: @val I tested my code in separate session and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach?

```
DF <- data.frame(V=1:5,V1=c("Place1-Place2-Place3-Place4-Place5-Place6-Place7",
                            "Place2-Place4-Place5-Place7-Place8",
                            "Place1-Place2-Place4-Place7-Place8-Place9",
                            "Place3-Place4-Place2-Place1",
                            "Place5-Place6"))

#Find all unique places in the DF
Places <- unique(c(str_split(DF$V1,pattern = "-",simplify = T)))
#Sort into order and remove blanks
Places <- sort(Places[nchar(Places)>=1])
#Count occurance for each Place
Place_Count <- sapply(1:length(Places), function(x){sum(str_count(DF$V1,pattern = Places[x]))})
#Plot
DFF <- data.frame(Places,Place_Count)
DFF %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Places,y=Place_Count))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]
First we find all unique places, then we count their occurrences. It should work for arbitrary number of rows.